# Remove low orders from Series

Tags: series-expansion

It is easy to truncate Series upto some order, say $n$. My question is how do I remove low orders? Let us say my series is a power series in $x$. I want to remove the terms with negative powers because they diverge at $x = 0$. I can simply write

s1-s2, where

s1=Normal[Series[blah, {x, 0, n}]

s2=Normal[Series[blah, {x, 0, -1}]

but Mathematica does not understand to cancel the removed terms because they are complicated. The solution would be to use Collect[s1-s2, x, Simplify], but this is horribly slow as I increase $n$ above even 2. I suppose I could simply delete the terms by hand, but the outputs are very messy, and there must exist a proper way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: It's going to be hard to guess without an example that reproduces the problem.  Well, obviously, given 4 answers already, it's not really hard to **guess,** but it's hard to test whether one's guess is at all helpful.  Another guess: Don't `Normal` the series and try `s1 - Normal@s2`.  That might force it to collect like terms but only simplify the low-order ones.

Answer (score 4):

Why not to subtract two expansions like in

```
t1 = Series[1/Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
t2 = Series[1/Sin[x], {x, 0, 0}]
```

Then

```
Normal[t1] - Normal[t2]
```

Out[3]:=
x/6 + (7 x^3)/360 + (31 x^5)/15120 + (127 x^7)/604800 + (
 73 x^9)/3421440

Comment: This one is my favorite.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. This is the one the OP says does not work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's a good reason for choosing a favorite :)

Comment: @Michael, well damn, I would have gone without the `Collect[]` myself. I really hope OP would actually tell us the actual series he has…

Answer (score 3):

If everything else fails, you can always do

```
Total[SeriesCoefficient[f@x, {x, 0, #}] x^# & /@ Range[0, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this approach is applicable to all series, but from a quick test it seems to work for rational exponents:

Looking at the `FullForm` of

```
ser = Series[Exp[x]/x^(2/3), {x, 0, 5}]
(* x^(-2/3) + x^(1/3) + x^(4/3)/2 + x^(7/3)/6 + x^(10/3)/24 + x^(13/3)/120 + O[x]^(16/3) *)
```

gives

```
FullForm[ser]
(* SeriesData[x,0,List[1,0,0,1,0,0,Rational[1,2],0,0,Rational[1,6],0,0,Rational[1,24],0,0,Rational[1,120]],-2,16,3]
```

As we see, `[[3]]` contains a list of coefficients, while the lowest and highest powers are given by `[[4]]/[[6]]` and `[[5]]/[[6]]` respectively. If we want to eliminate all negative powers we may simply remove the `-[[4]]` first coefficients from the coefficient list, and set `[[4]]` to 0 afterwards. That is:

```
ser2 = ReplacePart[ser, {3 -> Drop[ser[[3]], -ser[[4]]], 4 -> 0}]
(* x^(1/3) + x^(4/3)/2 + x^(7/3)/6 + x^(10/3)/24 + x^(13/3)/120 + O[x]^(16/3) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this as simple as

```
DeleteCases[s1, _*x^c_ /; c<0]
```

That is going to find all the terms in your series with negative exponents and simply delete them.